# itemController with real view instead of virtual view emberjs

Tags: ember.js

I have a {{#each}} handlebar helper with arrangedContent I use it like this

```
{{#each arrangedContent itemController='people'}}
  {{content.name}}
{{/each}}
```

The functionality of itemController is it generates a **virtual view** for each item

I want that on clicking a content name a new window should popup which can be done with view.
but since i have virtual view I am unable to do it.

**MY ATTEMPT**
What I imagined that if i create a new view and render it with help of {{view "App.PeopleItemView" then it might work

so it did

```
{{#each arrangedContent itemController='people'}}
      {{view 'App.PeopleItemView'}}
{{/each}}
```

and my people item view loook like this

```
App.PeopleItemView = Em.View.extend({
  layoutName: 'people_item',
});
```

But it does not work this way. I still am with virtual view

**Update**
I created a property called url in peopleController like this

```
url: function(){
        var pathArray = window.location.href.split('/');
        pathArray.pop();
        var newPathname = "";

        for ( i = 0; i < pathArray.length; i++ ) {
        newPathname += pathArray[i];
        newPathname += "/";
        };
        newPathname+="people/"+this.get('content.id');

        return newPathname;
    }.property('content'),
```

and then accessed it as suggested by @ppcano

Comment: what do you mean by "new window"? Do you want to show an application popup or do you want to show/hide person content when the user click the person name?

Comment: New browser window(tab)

Comment: Does this new tab link to a URL route of your Ember App or an external website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not wrong your content is being showed correctly, so you could create html link whose href value depends on your person content.

```
 {{#each item in model}}
      <a target="_blank" href="{{unbound item.personUrl}}">{{item.name}}</a>
 {{/each}}
```

If you want to redirect to an application route, use the [link_to helper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.LinkView.html). Currently,  it does not support to setup the target attribute, but a [Feature Pull Request](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/4718) is on the way..

Answer (score 0):

I think you get `itemController` wrong as it is not supposed to produce anything but instead wrap the item within 'contents'.

From [Ember.ArrayController](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html):

> Sometimes you want to display computed properties within the body of
>   an #each helper that depend on the underlying items in content, but
>   are not present on those items. To do this, set itemController to the
>   name of a controller (probably an ObjectController) that will wrap
>   each individual item.

By utilizing `itemController` the item can have computed properties, etc.

On the other hand, I believe you should use View' `templateName` property instead of `layoutName`. See: [defining a view](http://emberjs.com/guides/views/defining-a-view/).

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to accomplish this (if I understand correctly) is to use `each` like this:

`{{each arrangedContent itemView="item"}}`

This will loop through your `arrangedContent` and give every item an instance of your `App.ItemView`.

You can then access the item by `{{view.content}}` in your view template.

Have a look at http://jsbin.com/gufid/edit for an example.